# if statement php

Tags: php

What's wrong with my if statement?

```
$sMasterDID = 85487;
    if($sMasterDID != "78681" OR $sMasterDID != "85487"){
      echo "if";
    }else{
      echo "else";
    }
```

This should echo: 'else'. Right? and is not!!

If I do this the if statement works:

```
$sMasterDID = 85487;
    if($sMasterDID != "85487"){
      echo "if";
    }else{
      echo "else";
    }
```

I also tried the code removing the quotes from the number (Doesn't work)

```
    if($sMasterDID != 78681 OR $sMasterDID != 85487)
```

Comment: @casper thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: @watcher No problem.  Thanks for participating in the [Summer of Love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)

Comment: @casperOne, this is very controversial in SO. The [meta question you linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate/) has several highly upvoted answers explaining the upsides of leaving such comments. Just because you don't like it, doesn't mean it's a rule.

Comment: @casperOne, I'm sorry but I disagree with you. You have the `Meta` to express your opinion about what's accepted by the SO community. Large number of people disagree with you, this place is moderated by the community of contributing members. Yes that means including you, but in no way means 2-3 people. I'll refrain from further discussion about this as the [community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23333/190495) has [clearly spoken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23349/190495).

Comment: @Adnan: you either didn't read the comment, or didn't read the answer you just linked to.

Comment: @Helder: if you find an answer that helps you to solve your problem, it's polite to "accept" it by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. If the answers aren't being helpful, please comment or update your question to clarify what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You have to look at what each individual statement evaluates to.

```
$sMasterDID = 85487;
$sMasterDID != "78681" //true
$sMasterDID != "85487" //false
```

When used in the statement, `if(true OR false)` evaluates to `if(true)` since `true OR false` is `true`, so `echo "if";` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `OR` wrong. `if ($x != '1' OR $x != '2')` will always evaluate to `true`. Use `AND` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sMasterDID = 85487;
if ($sMasterDID != "78681" OR $sMasterDID != "85487")
    {
    echo "if";
    }
else
    {
    echo "else";
    }
```

Let's understand what you do. The way you do 
the first clause: '$sMasterDID' equals true
the second clause '$sMasterDID' equals false

You have to think in that way
If the first clause is true or false do the first, else do the second; but when
you check if $sMasterDID differs from 85487, its false because "$sMasterDID = 85487" before. So, it wOULD do the second statement; but WHEN you put the first clause
asking if '$sMasterDID' differs from 85487 its true.

You have this result in IF clause:

IF (TRUE) OR (FALSE) that always results TRUE so we never run the second clause.

Understood?

See the boolean algebra for better understanding.

> OR
>   FALSE + FALSE = FALSE
>   FALSE + TRUE  = TRUE 
>   TRUE  + FALSE = TRUE
>   TRUE  + TRUE  = TRUE
>   
>   Remember the boolean algebra.

Answer (score 0):

The or operator is not an **exclusive or**. If one of the values in your if

`$sMasterDID != "78681"`

evaluates to true, the entire statement evaluates to true.